# Get total number of rows meeting WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a search application, and I want to figure out how many results a certain query fetches in order to calculate how many pages of results there are. I basically have:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE conditions LIMIT $page*$items, $items");
```

Do I have to do a query w/o the limit clause to get the total number, or is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table WHERE conditions
```

Comment: Is this better than using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM table
  WHERE conditions
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using PHP. Once you've run the query, why don't you [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) in PHP? That way you won't need to run two queries.

Comment: I approve of this too, didn't see the php tag.

Comment: Yes, it will. But it is easier for you if you check it yourself than asking here :)

Comment: This would return the number of rows in the result, i.e. the LIMIT number, unless there were fewer results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page_count=10 // no of rows per page 
$record=mysql_query("select count(*) from table where conditions");
$row=mysql_fetch_row[0];

$no_of_pages = ceil($row/$page_count);
```